# How to parse json with array to presenter with collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, presenter

I receive from external service **JSON** with trainings information for my current_user(by email).

```
{
    “id:”5357c5d17303b5357c5d173078”,
    “email”:”some@email.com”,
    ”trainings”:[
        {
            “training_id“: “5357c4e5d61f15357c4e5d622f“,
            “name”: ”training 1”,
            “state”: “started”
        },
        {
            “training_id“: “5357af490fcda5357af490fd15“,
            “name”: ”training 2”,
            “state”: “finished”
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON and present it on my page. So I thought about presenter.

```
class EducationPresenter
  attr_reader :email, :trainings

  def initialize json
    @email = json['email']
    @trainings = json['trainings']
  end
end
```

and

so now I can use it in my views like that:

```
Email: <%= @presenter.email %>
<% @presenter.trainings.each do |training| %>
Training: <%= training['training_id'] %>
<% end %>
```

How I can also parse and convert JSON to some Object to be able to use it like that:

```
@presenter.training.each {|t| t.state }
```

Is the presenter god way to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) :

```
class EducationPresenter
  attr_reader :presneter

  def initialize json
    json_hash = JSON.parse(json)
    @presneter = OpenStruct.new(
                                email: json_hash['email'],
                                trainings: json_hash['trainings']
                               )
  end
end
```

Read [`Parsing JSON`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Parsing+JSON) to understand this and also [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Now you create your object,

```
 @education_presenter = EducationPresenter.new(json_string)
```

And view :

```
Email: <%= @education_presenter.presenter.email %>
<% @education_presenter.presenter.trainings.each do |training| %>
Training: <%= training['training_id'] %>
<% end %>
```